# Save elements values as a list from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I would like to save all datas from a table from different iframes. The table structure looks like that in the iframe:

```
<iframe title="Music_93737192">
<input id="R28_1" type="text" value="Rock N Roll" />d <br />
<input id="R28_2" type="text" value="Pop" /><br />
<input id="R28_3" type="text" value="Hip-Hop" /><br />
<input id="R28_4" type="text" value="Jazz" /></p>
```

The code below collect the first data perfectly.

```
var matches = document.querySelector('[title^="Music_"]').contentWindow.document.getElementById('R28_1').value;
alert(matches);
```

What method i can collect all datas to one list/array/variable from the table if every page has different number of rows? In the future I would like to match that datas to my own list.

Comment: Instead of accessing the inputs by id, use `getElementsByTagName` and loop over the resulting node list … (Maybe additionally filter by type inside the loop, or use querySelectorAll so that you can use attribute selectors to begin with, if there might be other input fields as well.)

Comment: In the iframe there is a lot of other table with the same structure. How can i use getElementsByTagName to count only the id R28_* inputs? Thats not count anything: `var matches = document.querySelector('[title^="Music_ "]').document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
alert(matches);`